Issue with Custom Sign-In Page Using NextAuth and Localization Middleware in Next.js
I'm working on a Next.js 14 project with localization setup using the following libraries:
i18next(23.11.5), i18next-browser-languagedetector(8.0.0), i18next-resources-to-backend(1.2.1), and react-i18next (14.1.2).
I have implemented a middleware to handle language detection, which works fine. Here is the middleware code:
import acceptLanguage from "accept-language";
import { fallbackLng, languages } from "./localization-setting";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

acceptLanguage.languages(languages);

const cookieName = "i18next";

export function handleLanguageMiddleware(req: any) {
  if (req.nextUrl.pathname.indexOf("chrome") > -1) return NextResponse.next();
  
  let lang;

  if (req.cookies.has(cookieName)) {
    lang = acceptLanguage.get(req.cookies.get(cookieName).value);
  }
  if (!lang) {
    lang = acceptLanguage.get(req.headers.get("Accept-Language"));
  }
  if (!lang) {
    lang = fallbackLng;
  }

  if (
    !languages.some((local) => req.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith(`/${local}`)) &&
    !req.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith("/_next")
  ) {
    return NextResponse.redirect(new URL(`/${lang}${req.nextUrl.pathname}`, req.url));
  }

  if (req.headers.has("referer")) {
    const refererUrl = new URL(req.headers.get("referer"));
    const lngInReferer = languages.find((l) => refererUrl.pathname.startsWith(`/${l}`));
    const response = NextResponse.next();
    if (lngInReferer) response.cookies.set(cookieName, lngInReferer);
    return response;
  }

  return NextResponse.next();
}

Additionally, I've set up a custom sign-in page for NextAuth. Here's my implementation:
`import { EntraJwtPayload, jwtDecode } from "jwt-decode";
import { GetServerSidePropsContext, NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";
import * as NextAuth from "next-auth";
import { JWT } from "next-auth/jwt";
import AzureAdProvider from "next-auth/providers/azure-ad";

const defaultScopes = ["openid", "profile", "email", "offline_access"];
const requiredScopes = (process.env.AZURE_AD_SCOPES ?? "").split(" ");
const allScopes = [...defaultScopes, ...requiredScopes].join(" ");

export const authOptions: NextAuth.NextAuthOptions = {
  pages: {
    signIn: '/auth/signin',
    error: '/auth/signin',
  },
  secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
  providers: [
    AzureAdProvider({
      name: process.env.AZURE_AD_TENANT_NAME,
      authorization: {
        params: {
          scope: allScopes
        }
      },
      tenantId: process.env.AZURE_AD_TENANT_ID,
      clientId: process.env.AZURE_AD_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.AZURE_AD_CLIENT_SECRET
    })
  ],
  session: {
    strategy: "jwt",
  },

  callbacks: {
    signIn({ account }) {
      const grantedScopes = account?.scope?.split(" ") ?? [];
      return requiredScopes.every(requiredScope => grantedScopes.includes(requiredScope));
    },
    async jwt({ token, account }) {
      if (account) {
        return populateToken(token, account);
      }

      const tokenExpireCutoff = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 30;
      if (token.accessTokenExpireAt < tokenExpireCutoff) {
        return await refreshToken(token);
      }

      return token;
    },
    session({ session, token }) {
      session.accessToken = token.accessToken;
      session.accessTokenExpireAt = token.accessTokenExpireAt;
      session.user.roles = token.roles ?? [];
      return session;
    }
  }
};

export function getServerSession(...args: [GetServerSidePropsContext["req"], GetServerSidePropsContext["res"]] | [NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse] | []) {
  return NextAuth.getServerSession(...args, authOptions);
}

function populateToken(token: JWT, account: NextAuth.Account): JWT {
  const entraAccessToken = account.access_token;
  const entraAccessTokenExpireAt = account.expires_at;
  if (!entraAccessToken || !entraAccessTokenExpireAt) {
    throw new Error("No access token was present on the account");
  }

  const entraRefreshToken = account.refresh_token;
  if (!entraRefreshToken) {
    throw new Error("No refresh token was present on the account");
  }

  const decoded = jwtDecode<EntraJwtPayload>(entraAccessToken);

  return {
    ...token,
    accessToken: entraAccessToken,
    accessTokenExpireAt: entraAccessTokenExpireAt,
    refreshToken: entraRefreshToken,
    roles: decoded.roles
  };
}

async function refreshToken(token: JWT): Promise<JWT> {
  const refreshEndpoint = `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${process.env.AZURE_TENANT_ID}/oauth2/v2.0/token`;

  const body = new URLSearchParams({
    client_id: process.env.AZURE_AD_CLIENT_ID,
    client_secret: process.env.AZURE_AD_CLIENT_SECRET,
    scope: allScopes,
    grant_type: "refresh_token",
    refresh_token: token.refreshToken
  }).toString();

  const response = await fetch(refreshEndpoint, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    },
    body: body
  });

  if (!response.ok) {
    const errorResponse = await response.json();
    const errorMessage = errorResponse?.error_description ?? "[No response]";
    throw new Error(`Unsuccessful attempt to refresh token (${errorMessage})`);
  }

  const responseBody = await response.json();
  const newExpireAt = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + responseBody.expires_in;

  console.info("Refreshed token for user");

  return {
    ...token,
    accessToken: responseBody.access_token,
    accessTokenExpireAt: newExpireAt,
    refreshToken: responseBody.refresh_token
  };
}`

Here is my middleware setup:
`import { handleLanguageMiddleware } from "@/shared/libs/localization/localization-middleware";
import withAuth from 'next-auth/middleware';

export default withAuth(
    {
        pages: {
            signIn: '/auth/signin',
            error: '/auth/signin',
        },
    }
);

export function middleware(req: any) {
    return handleLanguageMiddleware(req);
}

export const config = {
    matcher: [
        "/",
        "/((?!api|_next/static|_next/image|favicon.ico).*)",
    ],
};`

My folder structure is app/[lang]/auth/signin.
The custom sign-in page isn't working. I'm unable to log in, and it redirects to myurl/auth/login. If I remove the custom login pages from NextAuth, the built-in page works fine, so I suspect there is an issue with my custom page implementation.
What could be causing the custom sign-in page to fail, and how can I resolve this issue?
I want to use Azure Entra ID Single Sign-On with custom sign-in pages.
